# Flutter Image.network not updated

Tags: dart, flutter

I had an issue about updating image using Image.network in stateful widget, it doesn't update when change the url inside set State  but when  i do hot reload, the image updated.

anyone have idea why it's happen ?

Comment: Can you please add some code that demonstrates what you tried? What Flutter versions have you tried?

Comment: i'm sorry i think i've made mistake about this question. thanks

Answer (score 14):

If the URL is the same as before, try to add some random querystring to the url, like:

```
Image.network(url + "?v=1");
```

Comment: Or even the current timestamp so that next time it is refreshed.

Comment: You are a god, the saviour! @Ian

Answer (score 12):

Give the Image.network a key with the url as a value.

```
key: ValueKey(url)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Well answered.

Answer (score 7):

### First you need to add a key to your widget

1. This wiil ensure that when the widget tree get rebuilded the image widget get
   rebuilded too

   ```
    Image(
    image: NetworkImageSSL(_imageUrlPath),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    key: ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100)),),
     ),
   ```
2. Then clear the image cache

   ```
   In my case have to clear image cache when image is uploaded to server
   Ex=>

   saveDataToServer(){
   if(onSucess){
   imageCache.clear();
    imageCache.clearLiveImages();
         }
   }
   ```

Comment: bro u have helped me alot with this solution

Comment: Oh i'm so glad to hear that

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the two image caches and adding a key worked, but it seemed like overkill.
Ian's answer was using a parameter in the url, but I wanted a bit of caching and did not want to request the server with a parameter.
So I ended up with the following solution that uses DateFormat from the intl package.

```
// Make parameter using DateFormat. This image will be cached for a minute.
var nowParam = DateFormat('yyyyddMMHHmm').format(DateTime.now());
// Use # instead of ? or & in url as nothing after # is transmitted to the server.
var img = Image.network(url + '#' + nowParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a key vaule to the Image.newtwork then u need to delete the cache evertime before it reolards.

```
imageCache.clear();
Image myimage = Image.network('url', key: ValueKey(new Random().nextInt(100)),);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we attach some random number to the url or some random key to the widget whenever you call **setState(() {})** method image will be requested from the server which is not good, so maintain version number for the url & update the version number whenever you want image to be updated.

```
class ImageRefreshDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ImageRefreshDemo({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageRefreshDemoState createState() => _ImageRefreshDemoState();
}

class _ImageRefreshDemoState extends State<ImageRefreshDemo> {
  final String _imageUrl = 'image url';
  int _imageVersion = 1;

  Future<void> _refreshImage() async {
    //call API & update the image
    _imageVersion++;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Refresh Demo'),
      ),
      body: Image.network(
        '$_imageUrl?v=$_imageVersion',
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: _refreshImage,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```