# How can I update a Network Image in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm currently learning Flutter and I wanted to try out Network Requests and working with Futures.

I want to show a random image from unsplash.com using their API and I want to change the image every time I press a certain button.

I tried implementing a function to change the image, but it doesn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: RandomImage(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomImageState createState() => _RandomImageState();
}

class _RandomImageState extends State<RandomImage> {

  static String imageUrl = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200';
  Future _imgFuture = http.get(imageUrl);

  void _changeImage() async {
    _imgFuture = http.put(imageUrl);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (Text('Hello')),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [

            Spacer(),

            FutureBuilder(
              future: _imgFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Oops, there was an error');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Image.network(imageUrl);
                } else {
                  return Text('No value yet');
                }
              },
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Change Image!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                _changeImage();
              }),
            ),

            Spacer(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the log ?

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting any errors. The picture just won't update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `Image.network` is keeping your image, for more detail to see It [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892074/flutter-image-network-not-updated). The solution for this issue is make a simple useless query to api, so the image will be identical differently in flutter.

```
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Change Image!'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                // _changeImage();
                imageUrl="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200?v=${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}";
              }),
            ),
```

The image won't change If you call the api too frequently, you might want to add a timer to prevent user from clicking too often.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked for me. I will try to implement a timer as my next step.

Comment: @DavidCsida , Glad It helps! You could mark as answer to let others know this is sloved :)

Comment: Nearly, forgot that. I'm pretty new here ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `_changeImage()` method, try replace `http.put` with `http.get`.

Comment: http.put works fine. I changed the URL as shown in the post above and now it works.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense when he used `http.get` in one place and `http.put` in another.