# How can I get an Image.network to update when the URL is changed with setState()?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My app is grabbing the user's profile picture from a link, but the link is not the same for every user/profile picture. Basically if the profile picture gets updated, the link changes so I want to ensure my Image.network displays the updated profile picture. How can I go about doing this? It seems like a regular setState() call on the URL does not work.

This is basically what I have:

```
Image.network(
          url,
        ),
```

then somewhere else

```
setState(() {
          url = 'another_url';
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Image.network not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892074/flutter-image-network-not-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is coming as the not unique key is generated while `setState`, As keys, should be separate as URL is continuously updating. Here for the key, URL can be used.

```
  Image.network(
      "Enter URL",
      key: ValueKey("Enter URL"),
    ),
```